# Why is this object reference exception firing in my C# MVC deployed app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue with my MVC application in production environment. It's a null  pointer exception in a place that, in my opinion, makes no sense. Also, I can't reproduce it locally.

**This is the stack trace:**

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at
> App.Controllers.ReservationController.Index(String id)  in
> C:\App\Controllers\ReservationController.cs:line 1593       at
> lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )       at
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
> controller, Object[] parameters)      at
> System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, IDictionary'2 parameters)      at
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
> controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary'2
> parameters)
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41()
> at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8'1.b__7(IAsyncResult
> _)      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult'1.End()
> at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)      at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
> at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
> at
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()

**This is the code at the line(1593) the stack trace refers to:**

```
this.CheckInvalidSegmentStatus();
```

**For some added info**:

- The `CheckInvalidSegmentStatus` function is a method that belongs to the controller I am calling it from;
- `this` is defined because I am validating it before calling the function that triggers the error: `if (this.CurrentPNR != null)`;
- I cannot reproduce this issue when running the project locally.

**More code:**

```
    protected virtual void CheckInvalidSegmentStatus()
    {
        //check if booking has invalid status segments
        var hasWLSegmentStatus = false;
        if (this.CurrentPNR.GDSReservation != null)
        {
            hasWLSegmentStatus = (
                from r in this.CurrentPNR.GDSReservation.AirReservations.NullToEmpty()
                from f in r.Fares.NullToEmpty()
                from q in f.Quotes.NullToEmpty()
                from si in q.SegmentInfo.NullToEmpty()
                let seg = si.Segment as Air.Segment
                where seg != null && seg.StatusCode != null && seg.StatusCode[1] == 'L'            
                select seg
            ).Count() > 0;
        }

        if (hasWLSegmentStatus)
        {
            this.CurrentPNR.ErrorList.Add(new Message
            {
                ErrorMessage = TTS.Framework.Resources.ResourceManager.GetText("Reservation.ReservationHasSegmentsInWaitListStatus"),
                ErrorType = ErrorType.Warning
            });
        }
```

Comment: can you put more code?

Comment: @MahdyAslamy I've edited with the code of the method that throws the error

Comment: @F.Almeida excuse me but i think your error is in your LINQ code i think it's not correct way to include children to a query and use of NullOrEmpty function is not correct.

Comment: see https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/06/10/use-lambda-expressions-in-linq-includes.aspx